# Do I need separate domain for MVC Web API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2

I am facing one problem.

I have 1 Presentation Layer Project using *ASP.NET MVC*. There is another project for Database interaction for *MVC Web API*.

Question: Do I need two domains ? One for *ASP.NET MVC* Project and another for *MVC Web API* project ?

Comment: The long answer because comments have a minimum length : No

Comment: No buddy, not needed.

Comment: @Tommy : Can you share any sample link that shows its usage ?

Comment: @BALAJI: Both are different projects under same solution file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two domains? No. However, given that you have two projects you will need two separate deployment locations. That means they'll either need to live at different *subdomains* (i.e. `www.domain.com` and `api.domain.com`) or under different virtual directories of the same domain/subdomain (i.e. `domain.com/web` and `domain.com/api`. You *could* put one of them in the root of the domain (i.e. `domain.com` for the MVC site and then `domain.com/api` for the Web Api, but you need to be careful at the point, as the Web.config for your MVC site will apply to any virtual directories under it, i.e. your Web Api.